# Heroku postgres no longer overwrites config/database.yml Rails 4.1.4 (and other questions)

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I'm very new to RoR and I'm having trouble understanding how to properly setup and use Heroku Postgres with my Rails 4.1.4 application. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

I want to have local PostgreSQL databases for development and test, and a Heroku Postgres database for production.

Here is what I've reached so far:

- I setup PostgreSQL by following heroku official doc [here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#set-up-postgres-on-linux)
- I installed the `pg` gem
- I changed my `config/database.yml` file:

  ```
  default: &default
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    pool: 5
    timeout: 5000
    username: franklin
    password:

  development:
    <<: *default
    database: myapp_development

  test:
    <<: *default
    database: myapp_test

  production:
    url: <%= ENV["DATABASE_URL"] %>
  ```

  I know from [here](https://discussion.heroku.com/t/rails-4-1-database-yml-no-longer-overwritten-on-heroku/550) that Heroku no longer overwrites `config/database.yml` for Rails 4.1.x applications and that I should (must?) specify `DATABASE_URL` in the production entry.
- I ran `rake db:create:all` which created my local development and test databases, and then `rake db:migrate`
- I `git commit` changes and then push my app to Heroku with `git push heroku master`
- I ran `heroku run rake db:migrate` and get the following message: `Running rake db:migrate attached to terminal... up, run.1227` (I'm not sure what that means?)
- I finally ran `heroku restart`

Then, when I connect to my development database, I can see the new table created by the `rake db:migrate` command, as well as its new data (form submission) I purposely created by running my app in localhost:3000. I get fully expected behavior.

But when I connect to my Heroku Postgres production database, the new table that should have been created by the `heroku run rake db:migrate` command doesn't exist. And my Heroku app doesn't crash when I add data to the nonexistent table (form submission).

Here are my questions:

1. Is my production entry properly configured in `config/database.yml`?
2. How do I correctly run migration to my Heroku Postgres production database?
3. Where does data from my Heroku app go if not in the table?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have a look here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/426 You shouldn't need to setup DATABASE_URL since it'll be merged

Comment: However, [this dev article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections#threaded-servers) indicates you should if using threaded servers (puma, unicorn and the like).

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to `https://postgres.heroku.com/databases`

There find the database of your app and you'll find the appropriate keys for your database. You can upload these as config variables and load them into your `database.yml`

Look into [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) for an easier way to handle your config variables.